# How can you add multiple sources in fetch

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch

I'm starting and one of the first things I'm trying on my own is how to add multiple sources to this promise:

```
    const getTodos = async () =>{
const response = await fetch('todos/resource.json');
if(response.status !== 200){
    throw new Error('Cannot fetch data');
}
const data = await response.json();
return data;
};
getTodos()
    .then(data => console.log ('Resolved: ', data))
    .catch(err => console.log ('Rejected', err.message);
```

I tried making different variables and using .then after to print them but that didn't work.

```
    const getTodos = async () =>{
    const response = await fetch('todos/resource1.json');
    if(response.status !== 200){
        throw new Error('Cannot fetch data'); // Error from the source
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
    const response2 = await fetch('todos/resource2.json');
    if(response2.status !== 200){
        throw new Error('Cannot fetch data'); // Error from the source
    }
    const data2 = await response2.json();
    return data2;
};

getTodos()
    .then(data => console.log ('Resolved: ', data))
    .then(data2 => console.log ('Resolved: ', data2))
    .catch(err => console.log ('Rejected', err.message)) // Error for json file
    ;
```

any tips?

Edit1:

I'm essentially trying to translate this

```
const getTodos = (resource) => {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.addEventListener('readystatechange', () =>{
        if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200){ 
            const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            resolve(data);
        } else if(request.readyState === 4){
            reject('Error getting resource');
        }
    });
    request.open('GET', resource);
    request.send();
})
}

// Then - To get data successfully, Catch - to catch error
getTodos('todos/food.json').then(data =>{
    console.log('Promise resolved', data);
    return getTodos('todos/sports.json')
}).then(data =>{
    console.log('Promise 2 resolved', data)
    return getTodos('todos/games.json')
}).then(data =>{
    console.log('Promise 3 resolved', data)
    return getTodos('todos/sportss.json') //Error example
}).then(data =>{
    console.log('Promise 4 resolved', data)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Promise Rejected', err)
});
```

into async await.

Comment: The OP might have a look into either or both [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

Comment: Regarding the so far provided answers are there any questions left? In addition, at SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to provide some feedback and/or accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return multiple things from a function, then you either need to return an array or an object. Two return statements will not work. As soon as the first return is hit, you're done. The only difference in an async function is that your single return statement determines the resolution value of the promise. You're still limited to one return though.

So here's an example which returns an object:

```
const getTodos = async () =>{
    const response = await fetch('todos/resource1.json');
    if(response.status !== 200){
        throw new Error('Cannot fetch data'); // Error from the source
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    const response2 = await fetch('todos/resource2.json');
    if(response2.status !== 200){
        throw new Error('Cannot fetch data'); // Error from the source
    }
    const data2 = await response2.json();
    return {
      data1,
      data2,
    }
};

// used like:
getTodos().then(result => {
  console.log(result.data1);
  console.log(result.data2);
});

// or with async/await:
async someFunction () {
  const result = await getTodos();
  console.log(result.data1);
  console.log(result.data2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From the above comment ...

> *"The OP might have a look into either or both [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)"*

```js
async function fetchTodoItems(resourceList) {
  return Promise.all(
    resourceList
      .map(url =>
        fetch(url)
          .then(response => response.json())
      )
  );
}

(async () => {
  try {

    const todoItems = await fetchTodoItems([
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/11',
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/21',
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/31',
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/41',
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/51',
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/61',
    ]);
    console.log({ todoItems });

  } catch(exception) {

    console.log('failed to fatch data with ...', { exception });
  }
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

`Promise.all` fails fast and the error/exception handling can be done at one place within the code ...

```js
async function fetchTodoItems(resourceList) {
  return Promise.all(
    resourceList
      .map(url => new Promise((_, reject) => reject('invalid api call'))
        // fetch(url)
        //  .then(response => response.json())
      )
  );
}

(async () => {
  try {

    const todoItems = await fetchTodoItems([
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
    ]);
    console.log({ todoItems });

  } catch(exception) {

    console.log('failed to fatch data with ...', { exception });
  }
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What is wrong with hinting the above methods? After all the OP's example code also just collects all the data, just in a linear way instead of the parallel loading of the above example code. The OP did not express whether one has to wait for one data package's arrival before one is allowed retrieving the next one. Also `Promise.all` fails fast and the error handling can be done at one place within the code.

Comment: This seems an interesting solution, I will look into it. Again I just started so I was following an example online but then just started wondering, what if I can add other sources to the async function, here (Edit1) is the longer version of the code without async and await functions

Comment: @JulioPalacios ... in the end you need to know whether you're looking for sequential loading like what you presented at first or if you look for parallel loading approaches where `Promise.all` and `Promise.allSettled` behave differently. Keep up trying and don't hesitate asking for help and editing your question continuously.